# React Native - Real-time chat/push notifications on PHP/MySQL back-end

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, socket.io, onesignal

I am developing my first React Native app and are struggling with the proper implementation of push notifications and real time chat. The attached image shows the **current layout without chat/notifications**.

The client application uses **Firebase** only for social network **authentication** (login) and image **storage**.
Everything else is kept **back-end** using **PHP/MySQL** which also communicates with Firebase for session token validation and email authentication (login).

[image: Current layout]

Now i want to implement a real-time chat function and push notifications but are struggling with the proper way of doing it. If i have understood correctly one way could be: [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) (for real-time chat using mysql for archive storage) and [Onesignal](https://onesignal.com/) (for push notifications)

Or is there a better way of doing this when using a PHP/MySQL as back-end?

Any ideas or input is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Basically your only two options are HTTP polling and websockets. It doesn't really matter what languages/frameworks you use, because it'll always come back to one of these. As for push notifications: your tech should never rely on push notifications in order to function properly, as these can easily get lost/delayed or the user can turn them off entirely.

Comment: Well i thought if maybe it was possible using the Firebase FCM or similar for the real-time data as chat for example but maybe sockets is the only option here then? The app is built so it dont rely on push notifications but if i understand correctly i cant implement this using sockets to get native push notifications and have to use library? It seems like two different things (native push notifications/real time data) when googling.

Comment: Yes, push notifications and real-time data pipelines are two separate things and you should implement both. Although it looks like FCM might cover this entirely with data payloads. My original point was just that, if you want to use PHP/MySQL, you would have to do either HTTP polling or websockets, since pretty much any other service uses these under the hood anyways.

Comment: @JoelRummel Thank you. I will accept that as a answer and implement Firebase FCM then as both real-time chat and real-time notifications. :)